# Double Arrow CSS

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

i'm trying to create a double arrow in circle but i can create just one.
I tried to use before but nothing to do.
This is the code:

```
<div id="basso">
    <a href="#" id="freccia">
        <span id="bottom"></span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Fiddle:
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ytyrmmw0/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used :before and copied the CSS you were using on the :after, only changing the margin-top and the position.

```css
    #basso
 {
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }


 #bottom
 {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 50%; 
 }

 #freccia:hover #bottom
 {
   display: inline-block;
   border-radius: 50%;
   border: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
 }

 #freccia:hover #bottom:after
 {
   border-top: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
   border-right: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
 }



 #bottom 
 {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 3em;
   height: 3em;
   border: 0.15em solid #333;
   border-radius: 50%;
   margin-left: 0.75em;
   transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
   
   
 }

 #bottom:after 
 {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 0.6em;
   width: 1.2em;
   height: 1.2em;
   border-top: 0.15em solid #333;
   border-right: 0.15em solid #333;
   -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
   transform: rotate(135deg);
   transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 }
  #bottom:before 
 {
  position: absolute;
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 0.3em;
   width: 1.2em;
   height: 1.2em;
   border-top: 0.15em solid #333;
   border-right: 0.15em solid #333;
   -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
   transform: rotate(135deg);
   transition: all 0.1s ease-out;
 }


 #bottom:hover:after
 {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 0.9em;
   width: 1.2em;
   height: 1.2em;
   border-top: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
   border-right: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
   -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
   transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
 
 #bottom:hover:before
 {
   content: '';
   display: inline-block;
   margin-top: 0.6em;
   width: 1.2em;
   height: 1.2em;
   border-top: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
   border-right: 0.15em solid #4183D7;
   -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
   -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
   transform: rotate(135deg);
 }
```

```html
    <div id="basso">
        <a href="#" id="freccia">
            <span id="bottom"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
```